# RSS feed for Spotify with PHP

Tags: php, rss, spotify, podcast

I want to make a podcast together with a good friend of mine.
I found out that we have to host a RSS feed as well as our sound files to publish our recordings to Spotify.
That itself isn't a problem - I'm familiar with web developing (HTML,CSS,JS,PHP).

The core of my issue is that I don't know which HTML/RSS tags Spotify needs in order to crawl my feed.
I've never used RSS before.

I found some help here:
https://www.patrick-saar.de/artikel/rss-feeds-dynamisch-mit-php-und-mysql-erstellen (German Page)

The general RSS format is something like this:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0">
  <channel>

    <title></title>
    <description></description>
    <language></language>
    <link></link>
    <lastBuildDate></lastBuildDate>

    <item>

    </item>

  </channel>
</rss>
```

But how do I have to fill those tags for Spotify? Does spotify need all of them? Or do I even need more?

Note / Edit: I know how to insert data from SQL with PHP - Thats not a part of my issue. It's just about the format itself.

Answer (score 2):

Check out Spotify’s [podcast specification document](https://podcasters.spotify.com/terms/Spotify_Podcast_Delivery_Specification_v1.6.pdf) — that describes what Spotify is expecting to see in your RSS feed.

You might consider using a podcast hosting platform rather than rolling your own RSS feed for your podcast. Here’s a [list of hosting services](https://podcasters.spotify.com/faq#how-do-i-get-my-podcast-on-spotify) that partner with Spotify to distribute podcasts.

Comment: Yeah that document is useless as it doesn't give you the correct information. I've been trying to submit an rss feed for the last 2 hours and I keep getting errors saying that I haven't supplied a cover art image, email address or author - all of which are present and correct (as outlined by the specs in that doc) in the said xml file. Search for this issue and you'll find that it's a known bug, but nobody can seem to offer an answer to it.

Comment: Finally found the solution. If anybody else is having submission errors because of the information you followed in the official Spotify docs read on... In the docs it tells you to declare the WRONG address for the namespace. `xmlns:itunes="https://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd"` should actually be `xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd"` - note the correct link points to a non secure http address. Hope that saves somebody else some headaches.

Comment: Is the SPEC link broken? I get: "Sorry, you do not have permission to access this page."
Maybe this is the new link: https://content-ops.atspotify.com/hc/en-us/article_attachments/4413124729499/Podcast_Delivery_Specification_v1.9.pdf ?